# How to update Firefox to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates, firefox

Can I use the Linux 64 bit version of the Firefox update!?

Answer (score 2):

*Firefox* is part of the Ubuntu 16.04 distribution package, so you will get *Firefox* distro updates when you update your system. A couple of different ways to do that...

### GUI Method:

Use the *Software Updater*, hit the <kbd>Super</kbd>, or <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and type, *Software Updater*, (without the quotes) and hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

or,

### Terminal Window Method:

Open a terminal window (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```